# Does the TYPO3 version in the <meta> tag always match the version currently in use?

Tags: html, content-management-system, typo3, version

I wanted to know the version of TYPO3 that is used for an existing website. Looking at the page source, I can see this, suggesting that TYPO3 version 4.7 is in use:
`<meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 4.7 CMS" />`

However, the webmaster* told me that it is in fact TYPO3 version 7.6.
I have no reasons not to trust this person, but my inexperienced self still finds it kind of weird.

I found some sources suggesting that the version shown in the `<meta>` tag should be the one that is in use. (e.g., see [this](https://www.lexo.ch/blog/2012/04/typo3-remove-the-cms-version-from-the-generator-meta-tag-without-touching-the-original-source/) and [this](http://typo3.3.n7.nabble.com/Removing-the-meta-quot-generator-quot-from-header-td92547.html))

**Question: Is it possible that the version of TYPO3 used for a website does not match the version shown on the page source?**

**Extra notes:**

- The website was developed around 2011, witch matches the date of release of TYPO3 v 4.7
- The backend seems to match TYPO3 v 4.7  (similar to [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/TYPO3_4.7_Backend.png))
- *I'm not actually certain this person is the webmaster, but he is at least involved in the hosting
- As an example, here is a site with a TYPO3 4.7 meta tag: http://asperasoft.com/

**Update**: As suggested by Mathias Brodala, I logged into the backend, the page title is $siteTitle [TYPO3 4.7.20]. While this is helpful, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta tag has been generated automatically which means that if it shows 4.7 it will be a 4.7 website. Everything else would be very strange.

Without knowing the URL it is of course impossible to tell

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be conflictiong with the one provided by Mathias and I cannot tell which one is right. As an example, here is a site with the meta tag showing TYPO3 4.7 CMS http://asperasoft.com/. However, this is not the site mentionned in my question.

Comment: Actually both answers are correct. But only a backend login can give you the answer whether this is a 4.7 or not. However, I'm not sure what you mean with _The backend seems to match TYPO3 v 4.7_

Comment: @Mathias Brodala Thank you for the clarifications. I'll update my question as soon as I get to log into the backend. What I meant is that the backend seems "old", but I have no knowledge of TYPO3 so it was just a guess.

Comment: @Mathias Brodala this [screenshot](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/TYPO3_4.7_Backend.png) of a TYPO3 4.7 backend definitely matches the one I saw on the website I was "investigating". (added it to my question, sorry for double comment)

Answer (score 1):

The meta `generator` tag was changed quite a while ago to [not include the TYPO3 version anymore](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/commit/d73a05d2bbdf54bc5294b6e41360e21e6d7929c3), so that's not an indicator for the TYPO3 version. There are various other indicators to determine the TYPO3 version from the outside but none of these gives an absolute clear answer.

The easiest way to check for the version is logging into the backend and checking the page title which will be *$sitetitle [TYPO3 CMS X.Y.Z]*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I unfortunately cannot log into the backend right now.  However, why wasn't the meta tag updated when upgrading TYPO3? In other words, why is it still shown right now?